# Returned json array contains objects with all properties missing

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Iam implemented a webservice using c# webapi,but my json response array is empty.

My code

```
public object Post([FromBody] castdet castdet1)

    {
        mid = castdet1.mid1;
        return Request.CreateResponse(jsonvalues(mid));
    }
 private object jsonvalues(string mid)
    {
        DataTable dtalcast = GetAllcast();
        foreach (DataRow drow in dtalcast.Rows)
        {
           string mouvieid = drow["MovieMasterId"].ToString();
           string actname = drow["ActorName"].ToString();
           string charname = drow["CharacterName"].ToString();
           if (mouvieid == mid)
            { 
              temp = 1;
              castdet.Add(new myobject(actname, charname));

             }
           }
         return castdet;
       }

 public class castdet
    {
    public string mid1 { get; set; }
    }

   public class myobject
    {
      string actorname;
      string charactername;
     public myobject(string v1, string v2)
       {
        actorname = v1;
        charactername = v2;
       }
    }
```

My json response string is like this [{},{}],its empty.What went wrong for me?

Comment: @Rob:this is the exact code that iam using,'castdet' is a list  that i was used for getting each values.I can manage to get those values.but unable to show inside json array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the fields of `myobject` be public.  Or better yet make them be public properties:

```
public class myobject
{
    public string actorname { get; set; }
    public string charactername { get; set; }

    public myobject(string actorname, string charactername)
    {
        this.actorname = actorname;
        this.charactername = charactername;
    }
}
```

(You may have other problems - your code is incomplete and does not compile.  Also, you should modify your methods to explicitly return the actual types being returned, not just to return `object`.  This allows for compile-time checking for type errors.)